# AngularJS ng-repeat get the index of the button clicked and used in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat

I got some code here, what I want to do is when I click the button I change the checkbox value and at the same time change the color of the button.
(check=red,uncheck=black for example)

I think it is easier to do it with jquery. My idea is to get the index of which button is clicked. change the value of the checkbox with the same index and the button color.

But I just cannot figure out how to select the button and the checkbox.

```
<div id="allcolrepeat">
        <div style="width:200px; float:left; margin:5px;" ng-repeat="col in allColumns">
            <input class="colCheckbox" type="checkbox" ng-change="changeCheck(col.displayName)" ng-model="checkvalue[col.displayName]">
            <button>{{col.displayName}}</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Don't use Angular AND jquery. Use Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive

> The ngClass directive allows you to dynamically set CSS classes on an HTML element by databinding an expression that represents all classes to be added.

*Code*

```
<button ng-class="checkvalue[col.displayName] == true ? 'red' : 'black'">{{col.displayName}}</button>
```

Another way of using it is

```
ng-class="{'red': checkvalue[col.displayName],  'black': !checkvalue[col.displayName]}">
```

Note: Declare `red` and `black` css class

Comment: @BaoyunChen, Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well here is a simple [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/apf8g2aw/)

You can do it with many ways, you can use `ngClass` or `ngStyle` (second one in the example) to change CSS styling, then you need only to assign the scope variable to the `ng-model` to change the checkbox value.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div id="allcolrepeat">
        <div style="width:200px; float:left; margin:5px;" ng-repeat="col in allColumns">
            <input class="colCheckbox" type="checkbox" ng-model="col.displayName">
            <button ng-style="{'background-color': color}" ng-click="col.displayName = 'CHANGED'; color = 'red'">{{col.displayName}}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', function ($scope, $filter) {
        $scope.allColumns = [{displayName: 'hello'}, {displayName: 'world'}];
        $scope.color = 'transparent';
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm using `ng-style` to change the button color :

```
ng-style="{background : status[$index] ? 'red' : 'blue'}"
```

But you can also use :

```
ng-class="status[$index] === true ? 'red' : 'blue'"
```

```js
function Main($scope) {
    $scope.allColumns = [{displayName : "1"},{displayName : "2"},{displayName : "3"},{displayName : "4"},{displayName : "5"},{displayName : "6"},{displayName : "7"}]
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="Main" id="allcolrepeat">
        <div style="width:200px; float:left; margin:5px;" ng-repeat="col in allColumns track by $index">
            <label>{{col.displayName}}</label>
            <input ng-model="status[$index]" type="checkbox">
            <button ng-style="{background : status[$index] ? 'red' : 'blue'}" ng-click="status[$index] = !status[$index]">OK</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in other answers it is better to use ng-style or ng-class for styling purposes.

But question was made and peoples from google-search will come to see how to get index with jQuery... So inside ng-repeat you can use '$index' ([ngRepeat documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)) variable so you can use it as data attribute or whatever you want. In your particular case you can make

```html
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <button data-index={{$index}}>{{item}}</button>
</div>
```

And with jQuery make $('button').on('click', function() { $(this}.data('index') });